# Как получить корневой контейнер из другой активити

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть `Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity`, в нем находится `FrameLayout` (`frame`) и некоторое количество `view`, вложенных в этот контейнер.

В другом классе, который ничего не расширяет, есть метод, который должен получить `frame`, как-то так:

```
void doSomething (Context context){
     ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) // ну и как-то получить frame из activity1 
}
```

Конечно, можно создать в Activity1 переменную frame, которая будет ссылаться на FrameLayout, сделать для переменной getter, и передавать как-то так:

```
void doSomething (Context context){
    ViewGroup viewGroup = Activity1.getFrame(); 
}
```

Но есть ли какой-то другой способ, типа "получить корневой контейнер из текущего контекста" или что-то подобное, чтобы не привязываться к названиям переменных корневых контейнеров или их id (т.к. метод будет обращаться к корневым контейнерам нескольких активити), а также не обращаться к view, вложенных в корневой контейнер?

Answer (score 2):

Без привязки не получится. Но можно попробовать id всех корневых контейнеров в каждом из activity выставить в root_container и сделать общий класс примерно таким образом:

```
class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    protected ViewGroup rootContainer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        rootContainer = findViewById(R.id.root_container);
    }
}

class Activity1 extends BaseActivity{
    private Foo foo = new Foo();

    private void test(){
        foo.doSomething(this.rootContainer);
    }
}

class Foo{
    public void doSomething(ViewGroup group){

    }
}
```

Важное дополнение: здесь не учено, что setContentView вызывается после onCreate.

Comment: Получаю ошибку 08-09 18:37:06.135 8022-8022/com... E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com...Activity1}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: в общем, не поняла, почему Ваш вариант не сработал, ибо знаний у меня пока маловато, но Ваш вариант меня натолкнул на другую мысль, и за это спасибо) Я поступила так: классе Activity1 я создала переменную FrameLayout rootLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content); и передаю ее в методе doSomething вместо this.rootContainer

Comment: @VolhaGomel NullPointerException в этом коде возникает поскольку `setContentView(R.layout.foo)`, позволяющий прицепить разметку к объекту `Activity` вызывается после `super.onCreate()`, соответственно любой вызов `findViewById(R.id.bar)` будет возвращать null до вызова `setContentView`, поэтому код выше и не должен работать в прямом смысле этого слова.

Comment: хитрый Вы товарищ... говорите загадками. Т.е., нужно переопределить метод setContentView в классе  BaseActivity примерно так @Override     public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
 super.setContentView(layoutResID);  rootContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content); и тогда должно все быть ок... кстати, я проверила, сработало! исправьте свой ответ, я плюсану)
    }

Answer (score 0):

Частично с помощью идеи [Rawnald Gregory Erickson](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229749/rawnald-gregory-erickson), частично самостоятельно нашла следующее решение:

1. сделала общий классclass

   BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

   ```
   protected ViewGroup rootContainer;

   protected ViewGroup mainLayout;
   ```

   }
2. в нем переопределила метод setContentView:

   @Override

   ```
       public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {

           super.setContentView(layoutResID);

           rootContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);

           if (rootContainer != null) {

               mainLayout = (ViewGroup) rootContainer.getChildAt(0);

           }

       }
   ```

И наследуюсь от этого класса:

```
Activity1 extends BaseActivity
```

Теперь можно ссылаться в Activity1 на mainLayout, искать в нем view с помощью метода findViewById, добавлять в него новые view, удалять их ну и т.д.

У меня все работает. Но, возможно, я в чем-то неправа, ибо не специалист.